# Proper conditional for a toggled element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".media").hide();

    $(".infobox").click(function(event) {
        var isVisible = $("."+event.currentTarget.id).is(":visible");
        if(isVisible) {
            $("."+event.currentTarget.id).slideToggle(100);
        }
        else {
            $("."+event.currentTarget.id).slideToggle(100);
            $("#media"+event.currentTarget.id).load("/mediabox/"+event.currentTarget.id);
        }
    });
});
```

When a user clicks an element I want to toggle a box to display and then load some content with ajax. That all works fine. But when it gets clicked again, I want it to toggle to hide and not load the content again.

As it is currently, it will toggle unhide and load the ajax. When clicked again, it just reloads the ajax and the element remains visible.

Any guidance for this javascript newb would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a counter/boolean and when the element is shown, check the value of the counter/boolean. If the counter/boolean is still equal to it's original value, load the ajax and change it's value. Or you could add a data attribute to the element the first time the ajax is loaded and then always check for the existence of that data attribute when the element is shown. If it exists, dont load the ajax data.

http://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/EKmyNb

```
if (!$div.data("loaded")) {
    $div.data("loaded", true);
    //load ajax data
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    var isEverLoadContent = false;
    $('.media').hide();

    // your code above
    else {
        if (!isEverLoadContent) {
            // Perform ajax request
            // if done set to true
            isEverLoadContent = true;
        }
        // Your next task
    }
    // Continue your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your problem to demonstrate visually how to make events according to your requirements. In my example the div will only get bigger on the second click but not at any other click. you could apply this to your loading problem.. This process is what I like to call flagging.  It has to do with setting variables so that you can  control the flow of a function or statement

```js
$(document).ready( function(){
  var happend = false;
  $("div").click(function(event){
    if($(this).css("background-color") != "rgb(0, 128, 0)" ){
      $(this).css("background-color", "green")
      console.log($(this).css("background-color"))
      // happend = false
    }else{
      $(this).css("background-color", "blue")
      if(!happend){
        $(this).animate({"height" : "+=50"})
        happend = true
      }


    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>button</div>
```

I didn't test it out because I cant get into AJAX right now. But I'm wondering if it will work for you or give you some ideas. It might not work for you because I didn't study everything that your code does but you could adjust the pattern for your liking.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var happend =false;
    $(".media").hide();

  $(".infobox").click(function(event){
        var isVisible = $("."+event.currentTarget.id).is(":visible");
        if ( isVisible ) {
            $("."+event.currentTarget.id).slideToggle(100);
        }
        else {
            $("."+event.currentTarget.id).slideToggle(100);
            if(!happend){
                 $("#media"+event.currentTarget.id).load("/mediabox/"+event.currentTarget.id);
                 happend = true
            }

        }

    });

});
```